# Retrieve IIS' ApplicationName in ASP.NET Core 3 application

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I'd like to know under what IIS' Application Name my asp.net core 3 application is running at start time. Possibly also Site Name.
There is a misleading IHostingEnvironment.ApplicationName which is something else (assembly name in fact).
Any idea?

Comment: You should be able to read from server variables, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-dev-reference/server-variables

Comment: Which one would provide it, perhaps INSTANCE_NAME? These are available with request, right? Anyway, I prefer to have it at start time (updated question).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no build-in method which could get the web application name. Here is a workaround.  We could try to use `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` to get the current identity name.

Normally, the identity name is the IIS web site name if you don't modify it.

Details, you could refer to below codes:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {

         string name = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;


        return View();
    }
```

Result:

Notice:Remove the IIS application pool is the IIS web site name

[image]